# Fabric Lakehouse PowerBI report: Couldn't load the data for this visual

Tags: powerbi, data-lakehouse, microsoft-fabric

We have created a lakehouse on microsoft fabric and put a PowerBI report on it, in direct lake mode.

The report is based on a dataset thats based on the SQL endpoint of the lakehouse:

[image: flow]

When created first time, everything works fine. But after first refresh or if we want to add data or visuals, or if we want to change visuals, nothing is displayed any more all the visuals:

[image: Couldnt Load data for this visuals]

It seems that PowerBI cant access the lakehouse any more.

Report creation works perfectly well on fabric warehouse.

How can we get this running on fabric lakehouse?

Comment: Contact support, looks like an issue. Fabric is in preview at this time, stuff like this will happen